# Magento 2.3 Ultimo Theme

Tags: magento2, ultimo

can somebody explain me how to change the product title visibility on top of the page (under breadcrumb) as a single line and not in the block above the add-to cart button?
i cannot find the source code where i can move that block!?

[image: how it's actually]

[image: how it should be]

Comment: In app\design\frontend\Mytheme\themename\Magento_Catalog\layout you will found "catalog_product_view.xml"  in this you can add  "<move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>"

Comment: you can find code in `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`